# Check a method with timeout throws an exception

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to test this method using jasmine.

```
connect() {
    client.connect();
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (client.getState() !== zookeeper.State.SYNC_CONNECTED) {
        throw new Error();
      }
    }, 1);
}
```

Normally I would test this method the following way:

```
it('throws error', function() {
    expect(connect).toThrow();
});
```

I know that `setTimeout` throws an error in a separate thread so `toThrow` does not work in this case. Anyone knows any other way of testing this method?

Comment: You can't; you need to change the method so that it's possible for the caller to find out about the error.  Use callbacks or promises.

Comment: Because you are making it  asynchronous

Comment: mock setTimeout under window, and execute the first argument callback immediately before `connect()` call for test